# Getting values from other sheets with a custom function

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I've defined the following function, and use it in sheet1:

```
function  myfcn (sheetname,rowstart,rows,columnstart,rows){
    var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
    // sheetname is a parameter to my function  
    var range = sheet.getRange(rowstart,columnstart, 1,1);
    var x=range.getFormula();
    return x;
}
```

In sheet2, A1 has `=100-B1`.  D1 has `=100-E1`. (and so on for 100's of formulas)
B1 has `=x+y`, E1 has `=q+p`.
x, y, q & p are named values. The 100-B1 is actually a MUCH more complex formula, but serves as an example.
My need is to create a .csv file (from sheet1) containing the VALUES (from sheet2) in A1, D1 etc. (using `=A1`, etc.) and the FORMULAS in B1 and E1, etc. using `myfcn`. The .csv file is then used as a pseudo-database where selected viewers (who are numbered) can see ONLY the row with their number. The viewers see a number and the formula (like `x+y`) that created it. There is a SEPARATE file that has a simple list of the VALUES of x, y, q, p, etc.

But when I change the value in sheet2, it is not retrieved. Also, when I select the cell in sheet1 that uses the function and press <kbd>F2</kbd>, Google says it is an unknown function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For a starter, you have `fromsheetname` there, but there is no parameter called that way. Should it be `sheetname`?

Comment: Yes @Norma, it should be sheetname. I have edited my post. The original has the name matching the parameter.

Comment: You also have columnstart instead of colstart, and lack the keyword "function" before myfcn. Also, you say you want to get "values", but the function uses `getFormula` instead of `getValue`.

Comment: Instead of `return(x);` the correct syntax is `return x;`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create a .csv file that automatically update each time that you change a value in your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

Custom functions are re-run when their parameters change. For example, if you have `=myfcn("sheetname", 1, 1, 1, 1)` and change some of parameters here, the function will run again. But if you go and change the content of cell sheetname!A1, the function will *not* re-run, since there is no indication *in the spreadsheet* that its output depends on sheetname!A1.

#### Alternative

To get all formulas from a sheet into another sheet as text, use a script function like this:

```
function copyFormulas() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == 'Watched Sheet') {   
    var data = sheet.getDataRange();
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Formulas');
    target.getRange(1, 1, data.getHeight(), data.getWidth()).setValues(data.getFormulas());
  }   
}
```

The function takes formulas from 'Watched Sheet' and puts them into 'Formulas' sheet as text. This script can run periodically, or on every edit, or on every change (including adding rows, etc). See [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: HI @Norma,the function call looks like this: `=myfcn("lmaster",ROW(D10),1,COLUMN(D10),1)`
which allows me to have the cell reference updated during copy & paste of the formula, while passing the actual reference, instead of the contents of that cell. Also, I removed the () around the x and that didn't change anything. And as you can see, I DO use the getRange and getFormula, but it isn't updating.

Comment: I added:
`ScriptApp.newTrigger("myfcn")
   .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
   .onOpen()
   .onChange()
   .onEdit();`
and got this error message.
 `You do not have permission to call forSpreadsheet`

Comment: My purpose of all this is this: I have a sheet that does computations with named values (codes). I need to DISPLAY the named values in each cell where they are used, so they can be saved AS TEXT along with their computed value. This allows my users to see the codes that were applied, in a separate file without access to the spreadsheet itself.

Comment: I guess i wasn't clear. In sheet1 I have formulas like =xx+yy. Several cells in sheet1 have such formulas. In sheet 2, I want to reference those cells (I know the specific cells) and display the value (as a number) AND the actual formula (as text) in cells of sheet 2. Later, I will copy ALL of sheet 2 and export it as an Excel sheet, then save it as a .csv file. That file will then be used to display the values and codes from a web-based program. I could use formula view, then copy & paste the formulas and values into Excel, but I want to automate as much of this as I can.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of clarity. I have re-written my original posting in hopes that you can see what I am trying to do.

Comment: @DocDJ I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for that function, but especially for the clue that sheet1 doesn't get updated when the data in sheet 2 changes even if it is referenced in sheet1. I think I can modify your function to only copy the formulas I need to be converted to text or set a non-cacheable value into sheet1 to force it to be re-calculated..  I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Instead of modifying the example form @Norma, I added a function to force a random value into a specific cell in the sheet using myfcn (which used getFormula) so it would be forced to update on any edit anywhere. This worked very well causing EVERY reference to `myfcn` to be updated which is exactly what Excel does. I can now copy & paste both the formulas and their results with one operation and not have to switch between formula view and non-formula view every time.

Comment: @DocDJ This is clever. Please post this as a separate answer, so that others will read (and upvote) it.